# Errors running python code on VB.NET python interpreter

Tags: python, vb.net, python-3.x, visual-studio-2012

I have installed and manually located the python interpreter in vb.net, now when the following code runs (executes), it shows some errors on it's DOS prompt (console). What's that mean? But it shows no errors while it's in the visual studio VB.net

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Visual Studio 2012\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 106, in exec_file
    exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
  File "E:\Visual Studio 2012\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 82, in exec_code
    exec(code_obj, global_variables)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py", line 11, in <module>
    target_str = target_hexstr.decode('hex')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Code**

```
ver = 2
prev_block = "000000000000000117c80378b8da0e33559b5997f2ad55e2f7d18ec1975b9717"
mrkl_root = "871714dcbae6c8193a2bb9b2a69fe1c0440399f38d94b3a0f1b447275a29978a"
time_ = 0x53058b35 # 2014-02-20 04:57:25
bits = 0x19015f53

# https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty
exp = bits >> 24
mant = bits & 0xffffff
target_hexstr = '%064x' % (mant * (1<<(8*(exp - 3))))
target_str = target_hexstr.decode('hex')

nonce = 0
while nonce < 0x100000000:
    header = ( struct.pack("<L", ver) + prev_block.decode('hex')[::-1] +
          mrkl_root.decode('hex')[::-1] + struct.pack("<LLL", time_, bits, nonce))
    hash = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(header).digest()).digest()
    print (nonce, hash[::-1].encode('hex'))
    if hash[::-1] < target_str:
        print ('success')
        break
nonce += 1
```

Comment: Usually, exact script would not fail in one call compared to another. The error is a runtime error. So VB.Net may successfully call the child process, being the Python script, but the script fails (not VB's fault). If VB.Net showed output of child process, it may return the above error.

Comment: The error message is independent of VB.net. What are you trying to achieve with this line `target_str = target_hexstr.decode('hex')`?